# Not logged-in user in a customer portal site

Tags: salesforce, report

How do I get the list of users who have not logged into a customer portal site at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The User object has a field called LastLoginDate](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_user.htm), you could report on this for users where `IsPortalEnabled` is `true` which indicates that they are a customer portal user if you're doing the reporting through code.

Of course, Salesforce's reporting engine can also be used to generate a report, you'll want something similar to this:

[image]

Unless you need the list in code for some reason (for instance, for integration with another system) then you should use the reporting engine and then you can schedule it for email delivery etc.

Comment: But it will give me the users who logged in the community last time.. but i want those users who haven't login..

Comment: I think the 'Last Login equals ""' bit will ensure it's for users who have never had a Last Login assigned e.g. never logged in

Comment: As Ray says, it's checking for a null value in the Last Login field, so as  long as you don't specify values in the date range (that's there by default) then it'll do what you need.